# Implementing search view gives null error in Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, user-interface, search

I am trying to implement a search view in my newly created application I am doing this by creating a custom search delegate that extends the search delegate, and it gives the error

it says, `child!=null is not true` I am not a fan of the ternary operator, and I am a newbie, so I don't have any idea what that means glad to seek help here

**code**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:train/pages/favorites.dart';
import 'package:train/pages/home.dart';
import 'package:train/pages/orders.dart';
import 'package:train/pages/Reservations.dart';

import 'Reservations.dart';


class Nav extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NavState createState() => _NavState();
}

class _NavState extends State<Nav> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Home(),
    Favorites(),
    Orders(),
  ];
  
  void _onItemTap(int index){
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(backgroundColor: Colors.black38,
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        leading: InkWell(
            child: Icon(Icons.menu)
        ),
        actions: [
          InkWell(
              child: Icon(Icons.search),
            onTap: (){
                showSearch(context: context, delegate: CustomSearchDelegate(),);
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 20,),
          InkWell(
              child: Icon(Icons.shopping_basket)
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 20,),
        ],
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Center(child: Text('FoodBee',style:TextStyle(
          wordSpacing: 3,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 24,
          fontFamily:'Roboto',
          fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
          color: Colors.white,
        ))),backgroundColor: Colors.transparent
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        fixedColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        items:const<BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home,color: Colors.white,),
            title: Text('HOME',textScaleFactor: 0.75,),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.favorite,color: Colors.white,),
            title: Text('SPECIAL',textScaleFactor: 0.75,),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.chart_bar_square_fill,color: Colors.white,),
            title: Text('ORDERS',textScaleFactor: 0.75,),
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: _onItemTap,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomSearchDelegate extends SearchDelegate {
  static List<String> dishnamehome = [
    'MEXICAN BURGER',
    'PIZZA',
    'GRILLED CHICKEN',
    'IDDALY',
    'DOSA',
    'EGG BIRIYANI',
    'CHICKEN BIRIYANI',
    'MUTTON BIRIYANI'
  ];
  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      InkWell(
        child: Icon(Icons.clear),
        onTap: (){
          query = '';
        },
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return
      InkWell(
        child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        onTap: (){
          close(context,null);
        },
      );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
   List<String> match_query = [];
   for (var dish in dishnamehome ){
     if (dish.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())){
       match_query.add(dish);
     }
   }
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> match_query = [];
    for (var dish in dishnamehome ){
      if (dish.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())){
        match_query.add(dish);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**error**

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building _SearchPage<dynamic>(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedTheme, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#6e4d8]], state: _SearchPageState<dynamic>#eac1c):
'package:flutter/src/widgets/basic.dart': Failed assertion: line 7121 pos 15: 'child != null': is not true.


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  MaterialApp file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/android%20studio%20projets/train/lib/pages/navigationsandmain/main.dart:12:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      new KeyedSubtree (package:flutter/src/widgets/basic.dart:7121:15)
#3      _SearchPageState.build (package:flutter/src/material/search.dart:486:16)
#4      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4744:28)
#5      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4627:15)
#6      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4800:11)
```

**This is flutter doctor**

```
[√] Flutter (Channel unknown, 0.0.0-unknown, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1826], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 0.0.0-unknown at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 9b2d32b605 (1 year, 6 months ago), 2021-01-22 14:36:39 -0800
    • Engine revision 2f0af37152
    • Dart version 2.10.5
```

Comment: What is your flutter version

Comment: @yeasin Sheikh '[√] Flutter (Channel unknown, 0.0.0-unknown, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1826], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 0.0.0-unknown at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 9b2d32b605 (1 year, 6 months ago), 2021-01-22 14:36:39 -0800
    • Engine revision 2f0af37152
    • Dart version 2.10.5'

Comment: Please don't SHOUT when posting here. Text in ALL CAPS  is more difficult to read and understand, and it won't get you help any faster. It's also rather impolite to SHOUT at people you're asking for **free help** to solve **your problem**.

Comment: @Ken White sorry you felt that way I was not aware that CAPS had the  meaning of shouting I will change the title right now I really don't mean to shout it's just because of my poor English knowledge I guess it would be great if you have a solution for me

Comment: This version ; dont know. try reinstalling the sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, update your Flutter version to the latest one. The version you're using doesn't have null-safety and a lot of warnings/errors doesn't even appear to you.

The problem is that both `buildResults` and `buildSuggestions` functions in `CustomSearchDelegate` don't return a widget. When a function doesn't return anything it returns `null` instead and this throws the error you've mentioned. On the newest Flutter version, this is a compilation error instead of a runtime error and is much easier to catch.